# корректное отображение двух изображений в ячейке таблицы

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Доброго времени суток. в ходе написания программы столкнулся с такой проблемой. есть массив json results, где хранятся различные данные, включая url изображения, которое нужно отобразить в uitableviewcell. задачей является отображение двух изображений в одной ячейке при повороте устройства в ландшафтную ориентацию. пока что получилось отобразить два одинаковых изображения, в остальных случаях индекс выходил за границы массива, а также первое изображение из следующей ячейки повторяло второе изображение из предыдущей. как необходимо отредактировать мой код, чтобы можно было выводить два разных изображения из массива results и при этом не столкнуться с тем, что в следующей ячейке будет выводится второе изображение из предыдущей?

собственно, код:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight: //view two pictures in cell when device orientation is landscape
        cell.entry = self.results?[indexPath.row]
        cell.nextEntry = self.results?[indexPath.row]
    default:
        cell.entry = self.results?[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

в enrty и nextentry ячейке передаются необходимые данные (entry для первой imageview, nextentry для второй)

Comment: Т.е Вам необходимо при повороте в альбомный отобразить ту же информацию в 2 колонки? Или что то дополнительно?

Comment: по сути да. в портретной ориентации все отображается как и в обычной tableview, в одной ячейке одно изображение. при повороте мне нужно отображать изображения в две колонки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более правильный вариант - использовать UICollectionView, тогда безкостыльно можно конфигурировать 1, 2, n колонок.

По Вашему варианту - как сказано в ответе выше, делайте `tableView.reloadData()`

Но при этом, когда в альбомной ориентации, необходимо уменьшить количество ячеек вдвое, по Вашему примеру:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight: 
        return Int(round(Double(cellsCount)/2))
    default:
        return cellsCount
    }
}
```

И отдаете ячейки:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight: //view two pictures in cell when device orientation is landscape
        cell.entry = self.results?[indexPath.row * 2]
        cell.nextEntry = self.results?[indexPath.row * 2 + 1]
    default:
        cell.entry = self.results?[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

Не забудьте проверить на выход за границы массива.

Comment: спасибо, переделал свою реализацию под UICollectionView

Answer (score 1):

1) При повороте устройства, необходимо делать `tableView.reloadData()` иначе ваша таблица не знает, что надо перезагрузится и поменять картинку.

2) Так как ячейки переиспользуются, то и картинка может повторятся, для избежания этой проблемы, скидывайте картинку в `nil` (`cell.nextEntry = nil`) и потом устанавливайте нужную картинку (`cell.nextEntry = self.results?[indexPath.row]`)